# Get Message metadeta for queue trigger azure webjob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

We have below code to QueueTrigger and we want to have message metadata(ie: dequequecount, lastretrival) at ProcessQueueMessage. Is there way to achive it?

```
 public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger(AppConstants.AzureBlobQueue)] string message, TextWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do Something
            log.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if(message.DequeueCount == 1)
            {
              //Logic 1 to notify 
            }
             if(message.DequeueCount == 2)
            {
              //Logic 2 to notify 
            } if(message.DequeueCount == 3)
            {
              //Logic 3 to notify 
            } if(message.DequeueCount == 4)
            {
              //Logic 4 to notify 
            } if(message.DequeueCount == 5)
            {
              //Logic 5 to notify 
            }
        }

    }
```

We have different logic for dequeue count == 5 we want to move message to db, we can achive it via queue-poison but just does not want to add another webjob/function for same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can, just change the type of `message` from `string` to `CloudQueueMessage`:

```cs
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [QueueTrigger(AppConstants.AzureBlobQueue)] CloudQueueMessage message, 
    TextWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
```

Comment: What if your message is a raw string, then you have to use `[QueueTrigger(AppConstants.AzureBlobQueue)] string message`, however you lose functionality like getting the "Id" or "DequeueCount".

Comment: Use don't have to use `string`, you can extract the message from `CloudQueueMessage`

Comment: This throws an exception that by default Json.Net serialization is used.